# OSX - Set Environment Variable for Android Studio via launchctl - works only after second launch

Tags: bash, macos, android-studio, environment-variables, launchctl

This is in my ~/.bash_profile, since I need Android Studio / Gradle to have access to this variable.

```
#CCACHE
export USE_CCACHE=1
export NDK_CCACHE=/usr/local/bin/ccache
launchctl setenv NDK_CCACHE $NDK_CCACHE
```

Interestingly, the variable is not set the first time I start Android Studio, but is always set the second time.

What am I doing wrong that it does not work all the time / the first time already?